# Remove Multiple Same Item From List Without Using Set

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

How can I remove several same items in a LIST
for ex:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

I want to remove all `1` values, such that output is:

```
a = [2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

I tried `a.remove(1)` but it only remove one '1' at the first encounter.
i try looking for comprehension method

Comment: @Aran-Fey thanks for a reference, kinda what i looking for, but still looking for the lesser complex, (kinda like '.remove()' thing), but thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't see how your question is different from the one I linked. You'll find all the conceivable solutions there. You just have to pick the one you dislike the least.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a list comprehension:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2]
cleaned_a = [el for el in a if el != 1]
```

Comment: need lesser complex, because i kinda dont need assignment to a new variable